# validar entradas a una base de datos desde diferentes dispositivos a traves de una aplicacion web en xampp

Tags: html

Tengo problemas para validar entradas a una base de datos a través de una aplicación web, lo estoy intentando hacer con un servidor xampp,y una aplicación web en html, ya puedo ver desde mi dispositivo android la base de datos, y la aplicación web, pero cuando quiero insertar datos, me parece error de conexión alguien que me pueda ayudar.

```
<?php abstract class DBAbstractModel { 

    private $db_host = "localhost"; 
    private $db_user = "root"; 
    private $db_pass = "my password"; 
    private $db_name = "base de datos"; 
    protected $query; 
    protected $rows;// = array(); 
    private $conn; 
    private function open_connection() { 

        $this->conn = new mysqli($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->db_name); 
        $this->rows=null; 
        $this->rows=array();

}
```

Me aparece solo el mesaje de error de conexion con la ip del ordenador donde esta el servidor xampp.

Comment: Puedes compartir tu código y el error que tienes? Por favor lee el [tour] y [ask]

Comment: <?php
abstract class DBAbstractModel {

 private  $db_host = "localhost";
 private  $db_user = "root";
 private  $db_pass = "my password";    
 private  $db_name = "base de datos";
    
    
 
 protected $query;
 protected $rows;// = array();
 private $conn;
 
 private function open_connection() {
  $this->conn = new mysqli($this->db_host, $this->db_user,$this->db_pass, $this->db_name);
  $this->rows=null;
  $this->rows=array();
 }...  
Me aparece solo el mesaje de error de conexion con la ip del ordenador donde esta el servidor xampp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de mi conexión:

```
<?php

$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = 'nacho';
$dbName = 'Test';

//Crea la conexion y elige la base de datos a usarse
$link = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if ($link->connect_error) {
die("Falló la conexion con la base de datos: " . $link->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, la conexión a la base de datos en el mismo ordenador si funciona, me dice "Datos guardados" en donde me presenta error es cuando lo intento de un dispositivo externo. lo que quiero es insertar datos desde otro dispositivo, no se si debo configurar algún archivo, para que me permita insertar datos externamente.

Comment: A que te referis con "desde otro dispositivo" ?? Desde donde hacia donde te querés conectar ??

Comment: Por ejemplo, desde un dispositivo android ver mi aplicación web en un navegador, en este caso la aplicación web es un formulario, para enviar registros a una base de datos en mi ordenador, pero cuando le doy enviar datos me aparece error de conexión, es decir, no me da acceso a la base de datos desde mi dispositivo android.

Comment: Mmm, desde Android no te puedo ayudar ya que no sé nada del tema. Porque no preguntás en el chat de StackOverFlow en español ?

Comment: ok lo intentare, muchísimas gracias aun así por la ayuda, aunq no presisamente sera un dispositivo android ya que podria hacerlo desde otro ordenador.

Comment: Con lo que te contesté en la repuesta debería andar bien. Estás cargando bien los parámetros DBHost, Table, User, etc ??

Comment: si, ya que dentro del mismo ordenador funcionan bien, pero si accedo desde otro ordenador al formulario para captar datos con http:// ip_server/ formulario. me deja acceder al formulario para capturar datos, pero cuando le doy enviar, es cuando me aparece "fallo la conexion a la base de datos".

Comment: debe ser porque el Host es localhost y lo debés tener que hostear en un servidor online para poder accederlo, no sé si me explico. Soy nuevo como vos en esto ... porque no haces una nueva pregunta y ponés todo el código así te pueden ayudar los que más saben ?? De paso pasame el link así yo tambien aprendo :)

Comment: si muchas gracias por tu ayuda.. :) si alguien responde te paso el link. gracias y no es un host online, es un host local pero no se como manejarlo,